# Why am I getting excessive CPU Usage with "clock( )"?

Tags: c++, timer, cpu

I'm trying to create a simple timer using the `clock()` method. When the application is executed, my CPU usage jumps from 0% to 25%. For a simple program that does nothing but count from 60 to 0 in seconds, it's a bit excessive.

I was following this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/

Any reason for this? Are there any alternatives I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The code you reference:

```
 while (clock() < endwait) {}
```

will clearly just chew CPU while waiting for the time to pass, hence the 25% usage ( one core).

```
while (clock() < endwait) { Sleep(1);}
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will I need to create another thread for 'sleep( )'? Because I need the timer running at the same time.

Comment: See above edit; obviously a more elaborate solution might apply to a more elaborate problem, but no, you should not need a new thread just to manage timers or clocks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boost::this_thread::sleep`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.sleep)

```
// sleep for one second
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your problem is not the `clock` function, but the `wait` function.

It loops until a certain time is reached. You should use a function that actually suspends your program, like the `sleep` function.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple timing tests are better run with some pseudo-code like this:

```
start = get_time()
for 1 .. 10:
    do_the_task()
end = get_time()
diff = end - start
print "%d seconds elapsed", diff
```

On Unix-derived platforms, `gettimeofday(2)` returns a struct with seconds and microseconds since the Epoch, which makes for some pretty decent resolution timing. On other platforms, you'll have to hunt around for decent time sources.